# What substitution can I make for blonde cane sugar in macaroons?

Tags: baking, substitutions, sugar, macaroons

I've found a beautiful (and simple!) looking [recipe](http://www.latartinegourmande.com/2010/03/21/coconut-lime-macaroons/) for coconut lime macaroons but it calls for blond cane sugar, which I haven't seen in any of my local supermarkets in the UK, nor have I ever used it in my baking.

Is anyone acquainted enough with either blond cane sugar or macaroons to suggest an alternative - especially a healthier alternative than straight up sugar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sucanat or turbinado sugar (Sugar in the Raw) would be pretty indistinguishable from blond cane sugar. One of them might actually even be the same thing under a different name.

[sucanat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004T330PQ)

[turbinado](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MBKF0U)

Here's a bit more about the *subtle* differences between sucanat and turbinado. [Time article](http://healthland.time.com/2012/02/29/better-than-sugar-5-natural-sweeteners-demystified/)

Here ya go, from Amazon UK [evaporated cane juice UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Evaporated-Cane-Juice-Sugar-793/dp/B005AHYMMA)

Also from Amazon UK [sucanat UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Organic-Sucanat-Dried-Sugar-Juice/dp/B005P0JP56)

And one more [turbinado UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_9?url=search-alias%3Ddrugstore&field-keywords=turbinado%20sugar&sprefix=turbinado%2Cdrugstore%2C632&rh=i%3Adrugstore%2Ck%3Aturbinado%20sugar)